# To print values of an array in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an object containing arrays.

```
{"ItemIsExportControlled":["true","false"],"OrderShippingDestination":["domestic","foreign"],"OrderShipping":["ground","air","sea"],"ItemStockStatus":["validInStock","invalid","validOutOfStock"],"OrderDeliveryTimeframe":["oneMonth","immediate","oneWeek"],"OrderPricingScheme":["scheme2","scheme1","scheme3"]}
```

I wrote the following function to populate values of each array in corresponding dropdown.

```
    columns1.map(function(item,idx){
     if(item != "" && item != "Is negative combination" && item != "Is don't care" && item != "Requirements"){
       headerFields.push(<th className="cell" key={item} filterkey={item} style={{wordWrap:'break-word',border:"1px solid black"}} showSearch={false}>
         <select type="text" className="form-control" name="filterOptions" id="filterOptions" >
            <option key="select">All Values</option>
              {self.renderFilterOptions(item)}
          </select>{item}</th>)
      }
   });

renderFilterOptions(item) {
      let filterList = [];
      if (this.props.state.getCartesianFilter != undefined)
        Object.keys(this.props.state.getCartesianFilter).map((check,i)=> {
          if(item === check) {
              filterList.push(<option key={this.props.state.getCartesianFilter[check]} value={this.props.state.getCartesianFilter[check]}>{this.props.state.getCartesianFilter[check]}</option>)
          }
        });
      return filterList;
    }
```

here, `this.props.state.getCartesianFilter` stores the object information that i have pasted in the beginning.

The problem with my code is, it is printing the values of each array in dropdown in a single option value. I want each value to come one after the other like in a normal dropdown. Can anyone please help me to rectify the issue with my code.
Thanks in advance..

[image]

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then you shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complex. You can simplify it as below.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-jdklt

```
 renderFilterOptions(item) {
    const data = this.state.getCartesianFilter;
    if (data) {
      return data[item].map(d => (
        <option key={d} value={d}>
          {d}
        </option>
      ));
    }
    return null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <select
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        name="filterOptions"
        id="filterOptions"
      >
        <option key="select">All Values</option>
        {this.renderFilterOptions("ItemIsExportControlled")}
      </select>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why should OPs approach be more complex than this? You've just separated OPs steps by first filtering the elements and then transforming them. OP does it all in one step/loop.

Comment: Thnx for simplifying it, But issue is still the same..All values are coming in a single dropdown option. Please see the attached screenshot in description so that you can get the exact issue i am facing.

Comment: Pushing in array, mutation should be avoided. and push in array is slow too. If time complexity is not piority. I think we should use array method more.

Comment: I found the issue. Please check solution.

Comment: while calling the function, you are passing a static value. If I am trying to pass dynamic value "item" then data[item] is coming as undefined. Please see tha updated code from where i am making a function call in description.

Comment: yes. your mistake is on itterating value. Instead of iterating, u using array. by default array toString.. combine value in one string.

Comment: can u create sanbox, to try